# JASIG CAS how to diagnose/monitor performance problems

Tags: cas, jasig

Users have been complaining about 30s+ delays in CAS authentication and our weblogs seem to support this.

I suspect it is one of our AuthenticationHandlers but I can't see an easy way to test this.

Any "out of the box" performance logging/warning I can turn on?

I was wondering about creating an AuthenitcationHandlerProxy class that would about slow checks but seems very heavy weight. I guess I could do a similar thing with AOP.

We are using JASIG CAS 4.0.7 with JDK 1.8 on RHEL 6.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have statistics, status and audit logs in CAS. Check out: https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/Monitoring-Statistics.html and https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/Logging.html. You should be able to configure what you need with perf4j.

Comment: Thanks. They look like helpful frameworks but am I right in thinking there are no inbuilt hooks for particular AuthenticationHandlers? ie I'd have to add annotations to the code?

Comment: Yes, you'll need annotations with your authentication handler and certainly some additional configuration in log4.